# how to set My Own android Hotspot Device name

Tags: android, networking, methods, wifi, device

I'm not asking about how to create a WIFIConfiguration 
that I want to connect to.

But I'm asking how to set my own Device SSID for my own phone?

```
private WifiManager obWifiManager;
obWifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo wifiInfo = obWifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
sendMessage(wifiInfo.getSSID());
```

The above code has no setter method. 
Only getter method. Please help!

I then stumbled upon [this article](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/debian-ubuntu-linux-setting-wireless-access-point/). it said the configuration file is located almost there for any linux OS. There is an SSID setting over there!

So i search on that location but found none! 
Probably android put it in a different order / place. Any clue?

Comment: `getSSID()` is the SSID of the WiFi network you are connecting to, not a WiFi network that you are setting up. There is no support for configuring the WiFi hotspot feature programmatically in Android through Android 4.4. I have not poked around the "L" Developer Preview to see if their networking enhancements added anything in this area.

Comment: so how could we set our own device name to be known (as hotspot / thethering) there must be a code doing it. @CommonsWare